# Where is the verse "harer nama harer nama....gatir anyatha" found?

Tags: identification-request

The verse quoted [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/adi/17/21/)

> harer nāma harer nāma harer nāmaiva kevalam kalau nāsty eva nāsty eva
>   nāsty eva gatir anyathā
>
> In this Age of Kali there is no other means, no other means, no other
>   means for self-realization than chanting the holy name, chanting the
>   holy name, chanting the holy name of Lord Hari.

It belongs to Brhan-Naradiya Purana 38.126 as per [this](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/16/186/). Is Brhan-Naradiya same as Narada purana? But I could not find the verse there in the 38th chapter.

What is the exact source of the verse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as you provided link that the verse belongs to Chaitanya Charitamtrita [Adi Lila 17.21](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/adi/17/21/), actually it occurs first in CC-[**Adi-Lila 7.76**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/adi/7/76/) before 17.21.

Talking about Purana, yes, Naradiya Purana refers to Narada Purana. As pointed out in the question the verse is not found in the 38th chapter of Narada Purana. The closet verse (with just a slight variation) I found from Narada Purana is:

> हरेर्नामैव नामैव नामैव मम जीवनम् ।
>   कलौ नास्त्येव नास्त्येव गतिरन्यथा ।।

IAST:

> harernāmaiva nāmaiva nāmaiva mama jīvanam ।
>   kalau nāstyeva nāstyeva gatiranyathā ।।

It's located as **115<sup>th</sup> verse of 41<sup>th</sup> Adhyaya of Narada Purana Purvardha** (Purva Bhaga) i.e `41.115`.

You can verify the quoted text at:

- Original Sanskrit text at Vedic Reserve site : [Nārada Purāṇam: Pūrva Bhāgam](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/puranas/narada_purana_purva.pdf)
- Sanskrit Wikisource: [Narada Puranam Purvardha : Chapter 41](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D-_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AA%E0%A5%A7)

Comment: I think then the numbering given in my question could be according to some other publication of the purana.

Comment: @Pandya 
Correct version is this:
harer nāma harer nāma
harer nāmaiva kevalam
kalau nāsty eva nāsty eva
nāsty eva gatir anyathā

Answer (score 1):

Hare Krishna. That verse is from Brhannaridiya purana 38.126. Naradiya purana and Brihan-Naridya puran are two different texts. The following is quoted from Wikipedia which, in my experience, is NOT always the best source for Vedic scripture and Vedic history but here I find it correct so far the difference between the two Vedic texts goes.

"The Naradiya Purana (Sanskrit: नारदीय पुराण, Nāradīya Purāṇa) or Narada Purana (Sanskrit: नारद पुराण), are two Sanskrit texts, one of which is a major Purana of Hinduism, while the other is a minor Purana (Upapurana).[1] Both are Vaishnavism texts, and have been a cause of confusion in Purana-related scholarship.[2] To prevent confusion, some scholars sometimes refer to the minor Purana as Brihannaradiya Purana.[1][2]

Unlike most Puranas that are encyclopedic, the Brihannaradiya text is focussed almost entirely on Vishnu worship, while the Naradiya text is a compilation of 41 chapters (20%) on Vishnu worship and rest of the chapters (80%) cover a wide range of topics including a large compilation of Mahatmya (travel guides)[3] to temples and places along river Ganges, and neighboring regions.[2][4]"

Hare Krishna

Comment: Namaste Welcome to HSE! You can have a look the help centre on answering questions as well as [guidelines for new users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)